# Angular this.path is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm getting an error "this.path is not a function"

I don't have "this.path" in code, I assume it's referring to my state, but I'm not running into any luck figuring out what the problem is exactly. The error is:

```
stateService.ts:530 TypeError: this.path is not a function
    at LocationHtml5Url.url (angular.js:13744)
    at Object.coreservices_1.services.location.setUrl (services.ts:209)
    at UrlRouter.push (urlRouter.ts:376)
    at updateUrl (url.ts:24)
    at TransitionHook.invokeHook (transitionHook.ts:44)
    at TransitionHook.runSynchronousHooks (transitionHook.ts:108)
    at transitionSuccess (transition.ts:507)
    at processQueue (angular.js:16832)
    at angular.js:16876
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17971)
```

Which is firing from some buried angular state routing I assume (since I don't use typescript). This happens when changing routes, after a resolve, but before the controller is loaded.

Also, even though this error appears, the next page does appear to load (console.log fires off in the controller).

If it helps, I think this is the last area the code reaches in my section before the error (this is bound within a very large state resolve for a parent routing system)

```
currentProfile: function($rootScope, UserProfileService) {
                    return UserProfileService.fetchClientProfile().then(function(profile) {
                        console.log(profile)
                        $rootScope.user = {
                            name: profile.fullName || profile.firstName
                        };

                        return profile;
                    });
                }
```

Comment: This may be a bug. What version of ui router are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being in my interceptor. While it looked like it worked fine, this was due to a resolution of a cookie LATE which is because it resolved randomly sometimes before, sometimes after, the next controller loaded (I didn't have this error all the time).

I normally do not have access to this page, unless you have the cookie. So it was going to the page, THEN the cookie would resolve, causing weird issues. It probably should reject with a different error.